# Clear cache without restarting the application

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a Web application that is hosted on a Linux server, using .NET core framework.

At the moment, I have to restart the Kestrel web server in order to clear the cache whenever I make a change to a HTML page.

Restarting the server also clears any user sessions, prompting them to login again.

How do I avoid restarting the server every time and clearing user sessions in order to apply the changes made to static HTML pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data protection is what I needed. Using this, user login is not invalidated when restarting the server.

[ASP.Net Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview)

```
services.AddDataProtection(o => o.ApplicationDiscriminator = "WebApp")
                    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("path"))
                    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(15));
```